# Kohana 3: Validation rule for has_many through relationship

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

Is it possible to create a validation rule in Kohana 3 that will validate the has_many through relationship?

Using the example on the [guide page](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships), a blog post can have many categories through the `categories_posts` table. Is there a validation rule that can be setup in the Post model to verify at least one category was added?

I tried the following:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'categories' => array(
            array(array($this, 'has'), array('categories'))
        )
    );
}
```

because I see that the `ORM::has` function will return true/false. But I think because 'categories' is a relationship, and not a field, the rule I wrote never gets checked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save `Post` before adding `has_many` relations. You can check `Post` for categories after saving, and mark it as draft if they were not set.

Comment: Yep, I had that problem. If I tried to add the `has_many` relationship before saving the `Post` I would get a database error because the `Post` didn't have an id yet.

Comment: Thats why relations must be checked outside the standard model validation.

Answer (score 0):

Woo, good idea. 
Focus in MVC design pattern. I think that's C business not the M.

```
if ($post->categories->find_all())
{
   //blablabla
}
```

Comment: Or I suppose I could just do `$post->categories->count_all()` and make sure it's greater than 0.

I was just hoping it was possible to do with a validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Since *categories* is external to the *posts* table, you'll want to use external validation. Create a function called `Model_Post::rule_has_valid_categories($submitted_categories, $post)` that returns a boolean denoting whether or not the submitted categories are valid for this post.

Then, create the extra rule just before you try to save the post:

```
$extra_rules = Validation::factory(array('categories' => $submitted_categories))
    ->rule(
    'categories',
    'Model_Post::rule_has_valid_categories',
    array(':value', ':model')
);

try
{
    $post->save($extra_rules);
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    // if categories rule failed, array will contain _external[categories] field
    print_r($e->errors('models')); 
}
```

You store the message in /application/messages/models/post/_external.php:

```
return array(

    'categories' => array(
        'Model_Post::rule_has_valid_categories' => 'Invalid categories'
    ),

);
```